Finding a function that satisfies an optimization problem
I've been trying to implement an algorithm based off of this paper, but I am struggling with one section, where we need to solve for a function.
In section 4.1 of the paper, we are computing two non-negative monotonically increasing, constant speed functions $f,g: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $M=(V,E)$ is a 3D mesh, and $M_C$ is a cut version of $M$. Having solved for $f$, to find $g$ "we solve an optimization problem whose objective is to minimize $\int_{M_C}| \langle J\nabla f, \nabla g \rangle - 1|^2$, s.t. $g(B)=0$. Here, $B\subset V$ is the longest connected path of boundary vertices of $M_C$ along which $f$ is strictly monotone."
How does one go about computing the solution to a problem like this?
